# What is the best way to proceed with a question for which I don't need an answer anymore?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close, questions, vote-to-delete

I've asked a question on SO, and after days of study on the topic of the question I've understood that what I've asked is not exactly what I need to know/to do with my C# code.
So, even if someone will answer it, I won't need it anymore.

In this case, what is the best way to proceed?

- Leave the question as-is, not-answered, waiting for hypothetical future comments from other users?
- Add an edit explaining that actually the question is out of *my* topic, and close the question?
- Delete the question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That depends on a number of factors:

1. Will having answers to this question help future visitors?

   If the answer is "yes" then leave the question, if "no" then you might as well delete it. This is hard to answer but look at the number views & votes and whether it's got any answers. If there are no answers and there are low views/votes on the question it probably not that useful to the wider world and can be deleted.
2. Was the initial question due to a misunderstanding?

   If the answer was "yes" then you might want to consider deletion, but bear in mind if you made this mistake then someone else might well do the same (which comes down to point 1!). In this case posting your own answer along the lines of:

   > I made a mistake in my assumptions and what I actually want to do is X, which I can do this way.

   would help others.

Obviously things are a little more nuanced than that. For example if the question has multiple answers or a single answer that has a positive score then you *can't* delete it.

Comment: Thanks! Since I still have some doubts about how to answer to your _point 1_, I thing I'll going with the second part of your _point 2_! I think it's ok to keep the question, and also pointing out that it was originally asked starting from wrong assumptions.

Comment: @Spaceman - yeah. #1 is tricky to answer. Look at the number views & votes and whether it's got any answers. If no answers and low views/votes it probably not that useful to the wider world.